# C segmentation fault 11 when implementing hashtable

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable

Doing a relational data structures project where I organize things into a hashtable. So far I've made an insert and lookup method and have no errors. When I try to run the code however I get this:

"Inserting CSG touples"
"segmentation fault 11"

I assume I'm not mallocing something correctly but I can't figure out what and considering it is saying "inserting CSG touples" I don't think its a problem in my createHashTable function. Heres my code

header file: CSG.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct CSG{
    char* Course;
    char* StudentId;
    char* Grade;
    struct CSG *next;

}CSG;

typedef struct CSGHASH{

    int size;
    CSG** table;

}CSGHASH;

CSGHASH* createHashTable(int size);

int hash(int CN);

CSG* makeCSG(char* Course, char* StudentId, char* Grade);

void printCSG(CSG guy);

//void printCSGLIST(CSGLIST guy);

int toInt(char* x);

CSG* lookup(CSGHASH *hashtable, char* course, char* StudentId, char* grade);

int insert(CSG* newGuy, CSGHASH* hashtable);
```

CSG.c

```
CSGHASH* createHashTable(int size){

    CSGHASH* hashtable = NULL;

    if(size<1)
        return NULL; // table cant be less than length of 1

    if((hashtable = malloc(sizeof(CSGHASH*)))== NULL)
        return NULL;

    if((hashtable->table = malloc(sizeof(CSG*) * size)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){

        hashtable->table[i] = malloc(sizeof(CSG));
        hashtable->table[i] = NULL;
        //hashtable->table[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    hashtable->size = size;

    return hashtable;
}

int hash(int CN){

    return CN%6;
}

CSG* makeCSG(char* Course, char* StudentId, char* Grade){

    //struct CSG tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG));
    CSG* tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG*));
    strcpy(tempCSG->Course, Course);
    strcpy(tempCSG->StudentId, StudentId);
    strcpy(tempCSG->Grade, Grade);
    return tempCSG;
}

void printCSG(CSG guy){

    printf("course: %s\n", guy.Course);
    printf("StudentId: %s\n", guy.StudentId);
    printf("Grade: %s\n", guy.Grade);
}

// void printCSGLIST(CSGLIST guy){


// }

int toInt(char* x){

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< strlen(x); i++)
        count += (int) i;
    return count;
}


CSG* lookup(CSGHASH *hashtable, char* course, char* StudentId, char* grade){

    CSG* list;
    unsigned int hashNum = hash(toInt(course));

    for(list = hashtable->table[hashNum]; list!= NULL; list = list->next){

        if(strcmp(StudentId, list->StudentId) == 0){

            printf("Course: %s\n", list->Course);
            printf("Student ID: %s\n", list->StudentId);
            printf("Grade: %s\n", list->Grade);
            return list;
        }
    }
    printf("doesn't exist\n");
    return NULL;
}

int insert(CSG* newGuy, CSGHASH* hashtable){

    CSG* list;
    CSG* currList;
    unsigned int hashNum = hash(toInt(newGuy->Course));

    list = malloc(sizeof(CSG));

    currList = lookup(hashtable, newGuy-> Course, newGuy-> StudentId, newGuy-> Grade);

    if(currList != NULL){

        printf("already exists\n");
        return 2;
    }

    list->Grade = strdup(newGuy->Grade);
    list->StudentId = strdup(newGuy->StudentId);
    list->Course = strdup(newGuy->Course);
    list->next = hashtable->table[hashNum];
    hashtable->table[hashNum] = list;

    printf("CSG inserted\n");
    return 0;
}
```

main file

```
/*
main4.c
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include"CSG.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

CSGHASH *testHash = createHashTable(47);


printf("inserting CSG tuples \n");

CSG* tuple1 = makeCSG("CSC101", "12345", "A+");
CSG* tuple2 = makeCSG("CSC101", "67890", "B");
CSG* tuple3 = makeCSG("EE200", "67890", "B+");
CSG* tuple4 = makeCSG("EE200", "45213", "D");
CSG* tuple5 = makeCSG("CSC173", "98765", "C");
CSG* tuple6 = makeCSG("MTH142", "47474", "A");

insert(tuple1, testHash);
lookup(testHash, "CSC101", "12345", "*");

//printCSGLIST(lookup(tester, "CSC101", "12345", "*"));
}
```

If someone can figure out what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it (sorry I know its a lot to trace through).

UPDATE

after a little debugging it would appear the issue is in the makeCSG function. Hope that makes it a little easier to trace through

Comment: Use gdb and find where it goes wrong.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(CSGHASH*))` just allocates space for a pointer and not for the struct. Same thing for `malloc(sizeof(CSG*))` later.

Comment: had that before still get the segmentation fault. Also sorry I'm pretty new to c and don't know how to use gdb. Did a little research and it doesn't look like its install yet on my comp.

Comment: `CSG* tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG*));`-->> ` CSG* tempCSG = malloc(*tempCSG);`woud do.

Comment: You are not initializing the pointers inside the structure.

Answer (score 0):

A fast pass turned up:

```
  if((hashtable = malloc(sizeof(CSGHASH*)))== NULL)
```

Err, this will allocate enough storage for a pointer to the CSGHASH and not the CSGHASH itself.  Think you want to get rid of the asterisk.  The following malloc() will also suffer the same fate.

Comment: had this before. Removed it but I'm still getting the segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

From CSG.h:

```
typedef struct CSG{
    char* Course;
    char* StudentId;
    char* Grade;
    struct CSG *next;

}CSG;
```

and in `makeCSG()` you are doing:

```
CSG* makeCSG(char* Course, char* StudentId, char* Grade){

    //struct CSG tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG));
    CSG* tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG*));
    strcpy(tempCSG->Course, Course);
    strcpy(tempCSG->StudentId, StudentId);
    strcpy(tempCSG->Grade, Grade);
    return tempCSG;
}
```

There are couple of problems in `makeCSG()`:

First problem:

```
CSG* tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG*));
```

Here, `tempCSG` is a pointer pointing to `CSG`. So you should:

```
CSG* tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG));
```

Similar issue in `createHashTable()`:

```
if((hashtable = malloc(sizeof(CSGHASH*)))== NULL)
```

this should be:

```
if((hashtable = malloc(sizeof(CSGHASH)))== NULL)
```

Second problem:

```
strcpy(tempCSG->Course, Course);
strcpy(tempCSG->StudentId, StudentId);
strcpy(tempCSG->Grade, Grade);
```

Here, `Course`, `StudentId` and `Grade` are of type `char *` and you are trying to copy some value to pointers whom you have **not allocated memory**. Allocate memory before using them.

So first you should do something like this:

```
CSG* tempCSG = malloc(sizeof(CSG));
tempCSG->Course = malloc(100);
tempCSG->StudentId = malloc(20);
tempCSG->Grade = malloc(10);
```

and then

```
strcpy(tempCSG->Course, Course);
strcpy(tempCSG->StudentId, StudentId);
strcpy(tempCSG->Grade, Grade);
tempCSG->next = NULL;
```

Also, make sure to check the `malloc` return after every `malloc` call.

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything envolving `char*` is wrong. You are not allocating the memory necessary to copy data into those buffers, in fact you are not initializing them at all.

A simplified version of whats wrong with your code:

```
char* Course;
strcpy(Course, "CSC101");
```

This is bond to cause fatal errors because we never allocated `Course`.

You have to either `malloc()` enough space to fit data in there, for each one of the `char*` in the structure, or declare them as arrays, so they are already allocated as you reserve memory for the structure they are in, but will have a fixed size determined at compile time.

Example:

```
typedef struct CSG
{
    char Course[16];
    char StudentId[16];
    char Grade[16];
    struct CSG *next;
} CSG;
```

This really is the easiest way to approach the problem, allows easy store and recover of this structure on a file if you wish to create some sort of basic database, and keeps the code cleaner, avoiding excessive memory management from a ton of `malloc()` and `free()` all over the place.